# Get attribute directly from function call. Python 3.x

Tags: python, function, class, python-3.x, attributes

I've made and example code here just to show what I want to get done:

```
import random
class myclass:
    def __init__(self,example):
        self.example=example


listexample = ["1","2","3","4","5"]

objlist = []
for i in listexample:

    objlist.append(myclass(i))


#Ok so here I got a list of objects



def examplefunction(listex, myproblem):


    randomnumber = random.randrange(0,5)
    print(listex[randomnumber].example)    # This works, of course
    print(listex[randomnumber].myproblem) # here, myproblem should be "example" and print one of my numbers.


examplefunction(objlist,"example")   # here.. I want this to get the attribute of the class
```

I just need to know if it is doable and approximately how? Don't know if I'm trying to do something that just isn't right but if this could be done it would be a good solution for me.  Maybe try to guide me to the right piece of text which can explain?

Comment: Sorry, your question is not clear. What do you to happen for `print(listex[randomnumber].myproblem)`?

Comment: I want it to print the class attribute that listex[randomnumer].example does.

Comment: That is what your previous line does. Did you want to print the *name*? Or did you want to print *all* attributes available on `listex[randomnumber]`, dynamically?

Comment: I made this example code so that I wouldn't need to copy the code I am working on. It's for an assignment and I don't want it to get stuck in the system that checks for plagiarism. The reason is that I have several attributes and depending on what I call in the function I want the proper attribute to be printed without having to write say .example  after it

Comment: That is not a problem. What is at issue here is that your question is rather vague.

Comment: @delnan: you read it better than I did.

Comment: It's vague because I don't know the right terminology I think. Thanks a bunch though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access a property dynamically using [`getattr`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
class myclass:
    def __init__ (self, example):
        self.example = example

x = myclass('foo')
print(getattr(x, 'example')) # foo
```

So the line in your `examplefunction` would be this:

```
print(getattr(listex[randomnumber], myproblem))
```

Comment: Ok this works. Very good first impression of this site's community. Cheers!